# Docker not working on Windows 10

Tags: docker

- I have Windows 8.1 in my laptop
- I installed Oracle VM and put Windows 10 Anniversary Update
- I have installed docker and enabled Hyper-V

But the Docker service does not work and throws this error:

> [12:44:35.012][DataKit        ][Info   ] Failed to set up server socket listening on "hyperv-connect://bc82778c-022a-45cc-8e60-eedbc6a4eb52": Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ENETDOWN, "socket", "")
>   [12:44:35.042][DataKit        ][Info   ] +6272us    Datakit  Starting com.docker.db.exe 09081b4 ...

Comment: I found similar issue for windows 10 on [docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-not-able-start-under-windows-10-version-1511-os-build-10586-420/17487/10). You may try looking for help there.

Comment: I have edited your question to improve the formatting and sentence construction a little. If you think there is more background information you could add to make the question clearer, you can [edit] it again.

Comment: wondering if and how you've fixed the issue, as I've come across the same error message